# jQuery on() method is firing more than one time

Tags: jquery

I made some jQuery code for preventing users from typing chars but only numbers:

```
     $("div").on("keydown", ":text", checkKey);

    function checkKey(e) {
    var n = e.keyCode;
    if (n == 13) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
        console.log('enter');
    }
    else if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        if (!((n == 8)
                || (n == 46) || (n == 9)
                || (n >= 35 && n <= 40)
                || (n >= 48 && n <= 57)
                || (n >= 96 && n <= 105))
        ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('ok');
        }
    }
}
```

end in html:

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" id="test" />
</div>
```

but whenever I type something, it seems it's being fired three times for example for one pressing enter I get three 'enter' in console and for numbers I get three 'ok', why is that? I also replaced it with delegate and live, live worked fine but delegate also was fired three times. thanks.

Comment: Can you include the code which `$("div").on("keydown", ":text", checkKey);` appears within. I would guess that it's this line that's being run 3 times rather than a problem within your checkKey function

Comment: I'm doing this code in an empty project with few line codes. that's almost all.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: the latest:  //code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate what you're experiencing. Here's a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vKDJq/) to demonstrate. Perhaps you can modify the fiddle to be closer to the source you're actually using and update it when the problem appears?

Answer (score 0):

isn't your input #test in three divs? I think you can have wrong selector in .on(). Try use something like that:

```
$("div").on("keydown", "input#test", checkKey);
```

Anyway paste full body please